# How to display video(captured as BufferedImage) on a JFrame?

Tags: swing, user-interface, webcam

I want to capture and display video from webacam. For capturing I am using [this JavaCV code](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.in/2011/12/javacv-capture-image-from-webcam.html) which gives **IplImage** that can be converted to **BufferedImage**. How to display this image on a JFrame ?

Note: I want to display video not single a image i.e. image should be updated continuously as it is captured from the webcam

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Swing: how to add an image to a JPanel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/java-swing-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel)  Also since you are using `Swing` you should use a `JLabel` for it there is really no reason (but you might want to) implement drawing yourself. See [the answer for details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2706730/613495), yet [another example is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9403763/613495).

Comment: @Boro Will there be a performance in using `JLabel` since I want to continuously capture and draw image ? This also makes this question slightly different.

Comment: Do not worry about performance just now. First build the capturing and displaying. Then you could test the two approaches yourself on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaCV lib its possible to draw the BufferedImage in JPanel with class Graphics without using IplImages.

Here is an example that display images from webcam in JPanel inside JFrame.

```
try {
        OpenCVFrameGrabber camera = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
        OpenCVFrameConverter.ToMat converter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToMat();
        Java2DFrameConverter converterBuffered = new Java2DFrameConverter();

        Frame capturedFrame = null;
        Mat matImage = null;
        camera.start();
        while ((capturedFrame = camera.grab()) != null) {
            matImage = converter.convertToMat(capturedFrame);

            BufferedImage bufferedImage = converterBuffered.convert(capturedFrame);

            Graphics g = imageView.getGraphics(); //getting the Graphics Class of the JPanel named as imageView
            g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 10,10, bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(),imageView); //this imageView is a JPanel component

        }
        camera.stop();

    } catch (FrameGrabber.Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Fail to capture frame");
        //this catch clause refer to errors on opening the camera or failure on capture of frame.
    }
```